# Eigenvalue properties

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ = 1, $\lambda_2$ = 2, and $\lambda_3$ = 3.

a - Find the eigenvalues of $B = A^2 − 2A + I$. (I is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix).

b - Find the eigenvalues of $B^2 − A^{−2}$

c - Find the eigenvalues of $C = (A − I)(A − 2I)(A − 3I)$. Is it true that $C$ is the zero matrix? Verify your answer.

I'm not sure how to solve these questions. How would I find $A^2$ or $2A $without knowing all of the elements of the $A$ matrix?

Are there properties of eigenvalues that can help me solve these, because I was never taught them.

Comment: Do you know [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem)?

Comment: For part (a), write $B=(A-I)^2$. What are the eigenvalues of $A-I$, given the eigenvalues of $A$? What are the eigenvalues of $M^2$, given the eigenvalues of $M$?

Comment: Roughly speaking, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ corresponding to an eigenvector $v$, then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$ corresponding to an eigenvector $v$. Take $f(x ) = x^2-2x+1$ for a).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

How you approach the problem depends a bit on what you already know. For the following, I assume that you know that given the fact that $\lambda_j$ are all distinct, that $A$ is diagonalizable.

So you have a basis $v_j$ such that
$A v_j = \lambda_j v_j$.

Given that the problem becomes rather simple. You just have to observe that the eigenvectors in your examples stay invariant (but the eigenvalues change)

As an example for (a)
$$B v_j = (A^2 -2 A+I) v_j = (\lambda_j ^2- 2 \lambda_j +1)v_j$$
and thus $B$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda_j ^2- 2 \lambda_j +1$.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I was able to solve parts a and c, however, I'm still working on part b. Using the equation λ2j−2λj+1 I was able to find that the eigenvalues of matrix B are 0,1,4. Using these values of B I found that the eigenvalues for B^2-A^(-2) are 0-1 = 1, 1-(1/4)=3/4, and 16-(1/9)=143/9. However, I think this is incorrect, am I doing this operation correctly?

Comment: @jimmy talon: apart form the fact that $0-1 =-1$ this looks completely correct to me...